# A regular expression to exclude part of string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string with only numbers 123433123412 and want to exclude the first 4 numbers and the last 2 numbers. Position 5 and 6 is always 33

I tried this regular Expression : `\b[0-9]{4}(33[0-9]{4})[0-9]{2}\b`
Doesn´t work, everything is mapped.

Can I exclude the first 4 and last 2 digits somehow?

Any help would be greatfully appreciated!!

Comment: Which language? It really depends on the regex engine. You can use `\b\d{4}\K33\d+(?=\d{2}\b)` assuming `\K` is accepted in your engine.

Comment: Is the string always the same length?

Comment: If the regex flavor allows, you may use lookarounds `(?<=\b[0-9]{4})33[0-9]*(?=[0-9]{2}\b)`, but what you have should be enough provided you can access capture groups.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.
Language is Java.
String could have 4, 3 or 2 initial digits but the rest is always the same.

None of them seams to work when i test them in regex101.com

Comment: Seems to be correct, yes everything is matched, but you need to look at the captured group and the issue should be solved. The first group has index 1 and not 0, 0 contains the complete match.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer :

```
String str="123433123412";
// No need for regexp...
String answer=str.substring(4,str.length()-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to understand how to use the capturing groups.  Your regex matches the whole string, however, the middle part that you want is captured as part of a group.  Check out this link:

https://regex101.com/r/Fmg5xJ/2

Look at the right of the screen where it shows what is in which group.  You just need to figure out how to refer to the captured group in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use:

```
String text = "123433123412";

String result = text.replaceAll("([0-9]{4})(33[0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})", "$2");

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s = "123433123412";
    String ps = "(?<=\\d{4})33\\d+(?=\\d{2})";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ps);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        String g = m.group();
        System.out.println(g);
    }
```

output:

```
331234
```

(?<=\d{4}): match the start 4 number but not include match result

(?=\d{2}): match the end 2 numbers but not include too.

Comment: Thanks you!
This solved everything, Full match and Group 1 only returned the requested result.